# How to redirect to a page using Primefaces commadLink and bundle.properties file

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a Primefaces commandLink which I have used it many times in my application. Now I want to store it's URL in a bundle.property file to make it maintainable. which xhtml attribute should I use to redirect it?

I already tried things like:

```
actionListener="#{bundle.Myurl}"
action="#{bundle.Myurl}" 
target="#{bundle.Myurl}"
```

Myurl also contains this: sales/index.xhtml

but none of them run as I want!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use command links for page-to-page navigation in first place. Use a normal link.

If you have an internal URL / (implicit) navigation outcome:

```
<h:link value="link" outcome="#{bundle.Myurl}" />
```

Or if you have an external URL:

```
<h:outputLink value="#{bundle.Myurl}">link</h:outputLink>
```

Your attempts failed because the `actionListener` and `action` attributes are declared as `MethodExpression` attributes, meaning that any EL will be interpreted as a bean action method. The `target` attribute has an entirely different meaning, which is exactly the same as the generated HTML `<a>` element has.

#### See also:

- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)